# Factorial with R

Tags: r, factorial

I can't calculate the factorial of 365 by using `factorial(365)` with the R logial, I think the capacity of this logicial don't allow it. How can I do with an other method?

Comment: Try `Factorial[365]`

Comment: @Nasser that doesn't work for me. Where does `Factorial` come from?

Comment: @user5783745 as you can see, the question was originally posted at Mathematica forum, so that command is a Mathematica command. Later this  question was moved.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `lgamma(x+1)` to get the natural log of factorial.

```
factorial(365)
# [1] Inf
# Warning message:
# In factorial(365) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
lgamma(366)
# 1792.332
# convince yourself that this works:
x <- 2:10
format(factorial(x), scientific = FALSE) == format(exp(lgamma(x + 1)), scientific = FALSE)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

floating point math can get you into trouble at times, but `lgamma(366)` is accurate for `ln(factorial(365))`

Comment: Question became turning into an annoying thing, anyways, thanks for your time @Dan. I don't have any other way to thank you, so, this is.

Answer (score 3):

For large number try to use `lfactorial` R.base function instead. or `lgamma`.

```
factorial(365)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
In factorial(365) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
> lfactorial(365)
[1] 1792.332
> lgamma(365+1)
[1] 1792.332`
```

Comment: @Gregor Why use lgamma instead of lfactorial?